# Doorkeeper Application not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I have Doorkeeper working locally but once deployed to production I am getting a strange issue. I am not able to create new applications, please see below:

```
$> app = Doorkeeper::Application.new :name => 'test', :redirect_uri => 'http://test.com'
=> #<Doorkeeper::Application id: nil, name: "test", uid: nil, secret: nil, redirect_uri: "http://test.com", scopes: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

$> app.save
   (0.8ms)  BEGIN
   (0.8ms)  BEGIN
  Doorkeeper::Application Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `oauth_applications` WHERE `oauth_applications`.`uid` = BINARY '56bf468e5a1d116e3daef75ecc49b6b6ba313a9a79815b5b4683d56851880c49' LIMIT 1
  Doorkeeper::Application Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `oauth_applications` WHERE `oauth_applications`.`uid` = BINARY '56bf468e5a1d116e3daef75ecc49b6b6ba313a9a79815b5b4683d56851880c49' LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
```

The oauth_applications table is 100% empty.

I am running this on the server (locally it works as expected), please let me know if you need any more information.

**EDIT:**

I have also tried:

```
$>app.save!
```

and get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Redirect URI must be an HTTPS/SSL URI.
```

Comment: `Redirect URI must be an HTTPS/SSL URI.` try adding `https://` to your redirect uri. You might need to install a SSH cert, depending on your platform (done automatically on heroku).

Comment: That worked! Thank you, if you put that as an answer I will mark it correct! I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk for my host, looks like i will need to find a way to get the SSH cert on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the following component of the error:

```
Redirect URI must be an HTTPS/SSL URI
```

it seems you are using a nonsecure (`http`, not `https`) endpoint for the uri. For some platforms (like Heroku), HTTPS support is automatically enabled, so placing `https://` in the uri should suffice.

For ElasticBeanstalk, it shouldn't be a terribly cumbersome process. See [their docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html) to get started. You'll need to purchase a SSL cert from your domain name provider and then find the option in the ElasticBeanstalk web configuration to upload and use a certificate (I think the option may be in the load balancer section).

Answer (score 5):

I have a solution for NON https uri's. In the doorkeeper.rb config file you have the option to set `force_ssl_in_redirect_uri` to `false`.

```
# config/initalizers/doorkeeper.rb

force_ssl_in_redirect_uri false
```

Turns out this is not an issue but by design :)

Comment: This helped solve my issue as I only wanted to disable for localhost testing of a deployed Doorkeeper app. Within the initializer @gregwinn recommends you can uncomment this line `force_ssl_in_redirect_uri { |uri| uri.host != 'localhost' }`. That will force ssl unless it is a localhost uri.